# How to fix the findIndex in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
DATA = {
 code: 'no1',
 name: 'Room 1',
 room: {
  id: 'num1',
  class: 'school 1'
 }
};

LIST = [{
    code: 'no1',
    name: 'Room 1',
    room: {
        id: 'num1',
        class: 'school 1'
    }
}, {
    code: 'no2',
    name: 'Room 2',
    room: {
        id: 'num3',
        class: 'school 2'
    }
}, {
    code: 'no3',
    name: 'Room 3',
    room: {
        id: 'num3',
        class: 'school 3'
    }
}]
```

`LIST.filter((x: any) => DATA.room.findIndex(y => y['id'] === x['id']) > -1);`

How to fix the `data.room.findIndex is not a function`?

I have LIST here which it will list all the data and DATA which is the current selected data.
What I'm trying to do is to filter the data where it equal to the `DATA`.

Comment: `DATA` defined as an array and you're accessing it as an object (`DATA.room`), then you're trying to invoke `findIndex` on `DATA.room` but it is an object, not an array

Comment: @AlekseyL. so it should be an array? so I will conver the room object to an array ? right?

Answer (score 2):

Your `DATA` should not be an array, as it should contain only one selected item at a time as multi select is not mentioned in you question. In Case you intend to keep 'DATA' as array of single object , below code snippet can help you in filtering out your selected data from 'LIST'

```js
var DATA = [{
 code: 'no1',
 name: 'Room 1',
 room: {
  id: 'num1',
  class: 'school 1'
 }
}];

var LIST = [{
    code: 'no1',
    name: 'Room 1',
    room: {
        id: 'num1',
        class: 'school 1'
    }
}, {
    code: 'no2',
    name: 'Room 2',
    room: {
        id: 'num3',
        class: 'school 2'
    }
}, {
    code: 'no3',
    name: 'Room 3',
    room: {
        id: 'num3',
        class: 'school 3'
    }
}];

var filterData = LIST.filter(x => DATA[0].room['id'] === x.room['id']);

console.log(JSON.stringify(filterData))
```